On finding a scalar function which leads to a covariant tensor by differentiation
I need to find a scalar (invariant) function $F$ that when differentiated, leads to a covariant tensor function $f$ with one live index as:
$$
 \frac{\partial F}{\partial \dot x^k} = f_k
$$
The quantities at hand are:

"i" number of constant scaling parameters that can be arranged on the diagonal of a square matrix $A_{ij}$ so that $A_{ij} = 0\ \forall i\neq j$;
"j" generalized coordinates time derivatives $\dot x^j$;
scaling value $\alpha$.

Note that the scaling parameter could be viewed as a co-vector of scaling parameters $\alpha_i$ where all the elements could be set to be equal to simplify things.
The resulting function looks like this:
$$
 f_i = A_{ij} \cos(\alpha \dot x^j)
$$
It is supposed to be covariant with one live index.
Initially I thought of
$$
 F = \frac{1}{\alpha} A_{ij}\sin(\alpha \dot x^j)
$$
which by differentiation with respect to $\dot x^k$ leads to the desired function $f_k$.
However, the selected function $F$ above does not look like it is invariant because there is the live index $i$.
Then I thought of the following:

arranging the scaling parameters from $A_{ij}$ on a co-vector $a_i$ (to maintain correspondence with $\dot x^i$;
arranging the scaling value $\alpha$ as a co-vector $\alpha_j$ (where all values could be set equal afterwards);
multiply the function by $\beta^j$, where $\beta^j$ are such that $\beta^j\alpha_i = \delta^j_i$ (which is the Kronecker delta);

then, $F$ takes a form that appears to be invariant
$$
 F = \beta^j a_i \sin (\alpha_j \dot x^i)
$$
By differentiation,
$$
\frac{\partial F}{\partial \dot x^k} = \beta^j\alpha_j \delta^i_k a_i \cos(\alpha_j\dot x^i) = \delta^j_j a_k \cos (\alpha_j\dot x^i)
$$
The problem now is that I end up with index inconsistencies, and more than one index is live. Additionally, this does not solve the problem because what I need in the end is something like
$$
 f_1 = A_{11}\cos(\alpha \dot x^1) \text{ for } i=1
$$
$$
 f_2 = A_{22}\cos(\alpha \dot x^2) \text{ for } i=2
$$
$$
 f_3 = A_{33}\cos(\alpha \dot x^3) \text{ for } i=3
$$
For which scalar function $F$ can I obtain the desired output?
